# Is the JavaScript loop right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to iterate through each period of a student and find the names of those students who are free at a particular period on a particular day. Following is the approach I have tried, and it is not working.
JSON for the MongoDB is given below

The primitive code, that is working is:

```
const monday = await Timetable.find({ "monday.first": true })
let names = monday.map(a => a.name)
console.log(names)
```

```
{
    "name" : "JOHN DOE",
    "regNumber": "12345",
    "monday": [{"first":true},{"second":true}],
    "tuesday": [{"third":true},{"seventh":true}]
}
```

```
    slots = . `[first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eight,ninth,tenth]
   days = [monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday]
   for(day in days){
    for(slot in slots){
    const day  = await Timetable.find({"monday.slot":true})
    let names = day.map(a=>a.name)
    console.log("Students free in "+slot+" are: "+names)
    }   
}
```

However I have been getting an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `slots = . \`[first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eight,ninth,tenth]` real code or typo here?